# How to cleanly handle unchecked conversion with generics in an interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

**Simplified Code Example**

```
public class SomeBaseClass {
}

public class SomeClass extends SomeBaseClass {
}

public interface SomeInterface {
public <T extends SomeBaseClass> T someMethod();
}

public class BestClass implements SomeInterface {
   // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Override
   public SomeClass someMethod() {
      return null;
   }
}
```

**More Detailed Code Example**

```
// Base config class
public class BaseConfigClass {
}

// Some interface for all config classes to implement
public interface SomeInterface {
public <T extends BaseConfigClass> T getConfig();
}

// Class 'A' Config
public class ClassAConfig extends BaseConfigClass {
public doThingOnlyClassAKnows() {
}
}

//Class 'A'
public class ClassA implements SomeInterface {
   // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Override
   public ClassAConfig getConfig() {
      return null;
   }
}

// Class 'B' Config
public class ClassBConfig extends BaseConfigClass {
public doThingOnlyClassBKnows() {
}
}

// Class 'B'
public class ClassB implements SomeInterface {
   // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Override
   public ClassBConfig getConfig() {
      return null;
   }
}

...

new ClassA().getConfig().doThingOnlyClassAKnows()
new ClassB().getConfig().doThingOnlyClassBKnows()
```

I have several various `SomeClass` which extend `SomeBaseClass` of which an interface has return types of. I am using `<T extends SomeBaseClass>` to enforce that the return type is as expected.

The issue is that Java is unhappy with this an provides the following warning:

> Type safety: The return type SomeClass for someMethod() from the type
>   BestClass needs unchecked conversion to conform to T from the
>   type SomeInterface

Besides just silencing the warning, I can avoid this by instead defining the interface as such:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T extends SomeBaseClass> {
public T someMethod();
}
```

But this ends up being very messy as this interface has several methods which each implement different base types; and I end up with a very long winded `implements` declaration.

Everything seems to be working as I would expect it to now but I feel as though my implementation is somehow wrong as I have to explicitly suppress this warning for each method defined by this interface.

Is there a clean way to design an interface like this without the warning but doesn't require a long-winded `implements` declararion?

Comment: Why is `someMethod` generic?

Comment: I'm surprised that compiles: `public SomeClass someMethod() {` doesn't implement `public <T extends SomeBaseClass> T someMethod()`, does it?

Comment: Yes, this is kind of dubious.  You only actually use `T` in one place (in the first code example).  It should probably be replaced by a concrete type.

Comment: @Sotirios Because I want to return a class which extends `SomeBaseClass` to ensure that certain base methods are present.

Comment: Then just make the return type `SomeBaseClass`.

Comment: I want the additional methods provided by `SomeClass`. `SomeBaseClass` just provides various base functionality.

Comment: Subtypes can make their implementation return type more specific.

Comment: @Sotirios Thank you! I thought I had to use generics to provide an `extends` constraint on the return type. Please provide your response as an answer an I will accept it.

Comment: Also accepting other answers if Sotirios is not interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the warning is displayed is because your solution is indeed not typesafe. A method with the signature `<T extends BaseConfigClass> T getConfig()` can return any subclass of BaseConfigClass. In particular, the following code will compile without warnings:

```
SomeInterface a = new ClassA();
ClassBConfig bConfig = a.getConfig();
bConfig.doThingOnlyClassBKnows();
```

but will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime. (Well, actually, it throws a `NullPointerException`, but I assume you replaced the `return null` in your real code :-).

There are a few solutions. First, in your example, you don't use that interface. If you remove `SomeInterface`, you can still do `new ClassA().getConfig().doThingOnlyClassAKnows()`. If that interface is indeed never used, remove it!

The cleanest solution is the solution you already mentioned: give the interface a type parameter to tell it what type of object it will return. I understand you don't like this because you would need a lot of type parameters, but it is the cleanest solution.

If you really don't want to add the type parameters, I would simply remove the generics completely:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public BaseConfigClass getConfig();
}
```

In subclasses, you can still can return the more specific type:

```
public class ClassA implements SomeInterface {
    public ClassAConfig getConfig();
}
```

But if you only have a reference to the interface you will need to add a type cast:

```
SomeInterface a = new ClassA();
ClassAConfig aConfig = (ClassAConfig) a.getConfig();
aConfig.doThingOnlyClassAKnows();
```

Comment: Thank you for citing an example where a `ClassCastException` would be encountered. My misstep is a perfect application for [liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Would you add a reference to this and possibly a short explanation of it for others?

Comment: @Zhro. I'm not sure if that principle really applies. The problem is not really the subclasses, but the signature of interface method. The signature allows to return any kind of subclass of `BaseConfigClass`, and the type checker expects any subclass of `BaseConfigClass`, but has no way to make sure that it expects the same subclass as is returned.

Comment: I am accepting this as the best answer. I think I should open a new question with regards to clarification on this principle.